# Is recommended to create classes for utility functions using React/NextJS?

Tags: reactjs, function, class, oop, next.js

We're creating a webapp with my team and we don't know if is a better practice use a "support" class with all the utility methods or use functional utility methods (like importing a file called utils.js)

For now, we're using a separated files inside a `utils` folder that we call the utility methods when we need them

The doubt arises since React introduced the concept of functions for its components in its latest versions

Comment: it's totally fine to use functional utility methods. Actually the function name for your components should begin by an uppercase letter and the file name suffix will probably be `.component.js` to separate normal function and function components.

Comment: This is a vague subjective question, but I'd recommend utility functions be exported individually to make them tree-shakable during bundling with a build tool such as Webpack or Rollup. If you build a utility library as a class and stop using some of the methods without removing them, your dead code methods will still get included in the code bundle. As individual functions, the bundler can remove them automatically.

Comment: Another way is using custom hooks? Or it's a bad approach?